# Must a landlord warn potential rentees about previous pest infestation?

Tags: united-states, california, rent

Must a landlord warn potential renters about previous pest infestations?

---

I am mostly interested in the following locations:

- California, United States
- Massachusetts, United States
- Paris, France
- Seoul, South Korea

I have a particular interest in bed bug infestation.

Comment: @Chad Looks similar to a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_defect to me

Comment: That involves sales not rentals though.

Comment: For the record I have had leases that required that tenants advise the landlord if they notice certain pests like roaches, bedbugs, and termites.  But I am not sure how it would have been enforced and definitely not a requirement of the law in Illinois.

Comment: @Chad Sounds like a useful clause, I'll keep it in mind next time I rent a place as a landlord.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Tenant Hub](http://tenanthub.com/infestations/), pest control is the landlord's responsibility. [NOLO](http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/california-required-landlord-disclosures.html) states that:

> When the rental agreement is signed, landlord must provide tenant with any pest control company disclosure landlord has received, which describes the pest to be controlled, pesticides used and their active ingredients, a warning that pesticides are toxic, and the frequency of treatment under any contract for periodic service. (Cal. Civ. Code § 1940.8, Cal. Bus. & Prof. Code § 8538)

It therefore seems that landlords would indirectly indicate there was a past infestation by the disclosure of pest control measures currently in place.